# How to make Ubuntu shut down faster?

Tags: shutdown

My Ubuntu 20.04 seems pretty fast at turning on in my laptop, but WAY slower at shutting down, sometimes taking more than 10 seconds. Other than holding down the power button, is there a practical solution for that?

Comment: 10 seconds isn't abnormal. Hit the ESC key during shutdown and see if there's a particular step that's taking longer. Edit your question and show me `top` in your normal run environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need this keyboard shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

for shutting down desktop, if you have a problem like slower at shutting down or pc can't shut down.

Comment: What does this do? Random keyboard shortcuts are scary, like random encounters with large strange dogs who have no owner in sight.